# Image inside rounded Div with Text

Tags: html, css

I was making a rounded div , with an image (already rounded) with text on the right side.

The text keeps overflowing the div . Also , the text is starting from the center of the div . I want it to be close to the image .

As you can see the picture : the image is not close to the edge , and the text is far from the image .

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqauF.png)

This is what I tried to do :

```
<div class="container2">
                <div class="image-container">
                    <img src="test.svg" alt="Image" />
                </div>
                <div class="text-container">
                    <p>Text.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
.container2 {
    padding-top:20px;
    height: 140px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #00000029;
    border-radius: 94px;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
}

.image-container {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;
}

    .image-container img {
        padding: 4px;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100%;
    }

.text-container {
    flex: 1.5; 
    padding: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain this better? Because I'm not understanding. I don't see the text overflowing and it's pretty close to the image, do you want the image to fill the whole div?

Comment: Also, tHe text is distant because you set `flex: 1` on the img's container.

Comment: @AJAnde : it's not close , the text starts from the center of the div . I want it closer to the image .

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : I'm still learning CSS so I may be doing some nonsense stuff.

Comment: Should the image be "attached" to the left, top, bottom edges? (without any space?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.container2 {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 140px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px #00000029;
  border-radius: 100svh;
  opacity: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: .5rem;
  /* Increase gap value to make space between image and text*/
  padding: .5rem;
}

.image-container {
  padding: 4px;
  height: 90%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container img {
  height: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.text-container {
  flex: 1;
  padding-right: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="container2">
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTEsQLvSHMFPa9yV2y_i9ifBdBA-vuFedWFHFLjUrDVB1OW1gppTwzM45Rl-l1yw09WtHs&usqp=CAU" alt="Image" />
  </div>
  <div class="text-container">
    <p>Nous construisons des architectures basées sur le Cloud, qui vous fournissent sécurité et adaptabilité afin de surmonter les défis communs qui découlent d'architectures rigides ou obsolétes..</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of the design your going for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <style>
    * {
      margin:0;
      padding:0;
    }

    body,html {
      width:100%;
      height:100%;
    }

   .container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:flex;
    justify-content:center;
   }

   .wrapper {
    min-width:90%;
    height:60px;
    box-shadow:2px 2px 12px 2px #efefef;
    border-radius:50px;
    margin:10px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    padding:12px;
    overflow: hidden;
   }

   .wrapper .image {
    min-width:60px;
    height:60px;
    border-radius:50%;
   }

   .image img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
   }

   .wrapper .text {
    margin:12px;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="image">
        <img src="../images/favicon.png">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <p>Hello Mcdonalds triad again</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how your code should be structured, it's using flexbox and it'll help make sure your code is neatly organized and that you have easy access to arrange and move around elements. Also, replace the image with yours. To stop overflowing, you might want to limit the text input, if you want to use it for users to input, you'll need to use javascript or some other techniques to limit the text input.

Comment: Why do you use `width:100%;` on `html, body` and `.container`??

Comment: When there's a lot of text in the content you're not overflowing correctly...

Comment: I used with 100% because that's how I usually do it, also it's simple and just resizes to fit the page.

Comment: Ok, I'll fix the overflowing then.